# PayPal Rest first call won't appear in sandbox transactions

Tags: rest, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to have a transaction that is completed and see it listed in my developer sand box.  I think this transaction, below is completed but it is not in my sandbox transactions list.  I followed the instructions on the paypal website for making a first call with the rest API.

Here are my two curl commands using my credentials and the returned access token.  I received my `state:created` for the payment.  But the transaction was not in my Sandbox Transactions.  How long does it take to show up?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Harry

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
>   -H "Accept: application/json" \
>   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
>   -u ".....:....." \
>   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.82.78... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*    start date: 2012-12-06 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-12-06 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.sandbox.paypal.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '......'
> POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic .......... =
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Language: en_US
> Content-Length: 29
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 29out of 29 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=384
< Paypal-Debug-Id: de62039a5a244
< SERVER_INFO: identitysecuretokenserv:v1.oauth2.token&CalThreadId=47502&TopLevelTxnStartTime=14b83d4e3f0&Host=slcsbidensectoken502.slc.paypal.com&pid=6295
< Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 16:45:42 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 461
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*","access_token":"A0151dMXKPrBCWFFucj132Nvw87sS5NFntFDhhfF8la3Wsg","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","expires_in":28800}

$ 
$ curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> -H 'Authorization: Bearer A0151dMXKPrBCWFFucj132Nvw87sS5NFntFDhhfF8la3Wsg' \
> -d '{
>   "intent":"sale",
>   "redirect_urls":{
>     "return_url":"http://example.com/your_redirect_url.html",
>     "cancel_url":"http://example.com/your_cancel_url.html"
>   },
>   "payer":{
>     "payment_method":"paypal"
>   },
>   "transactions":[
>     {
>       "amount":{
>         "total":"7.47",
>         "currency":"USD"
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }'
* About to connect() to api.sandbox.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.82.78... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.sandbox.paypal.com
*    start date: 2012-12-06 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-12-06 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.sandbox.paypal.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v1/payments/payment HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer A0151dMXKPrBCWFFucj132Nvw87sS5NFntFDhhfF8la3Wsg
> Content-Length: 324
> 
* upload completely sent off: 324out of 324 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId=19925
< Paypal-Debug-Id: d2b2c56f78e41
< SERVER_INFO: paymentsplatformserv:v1.payments.payment&CalThreadId=196&TopLevelTxnStartTime=14b83d6cc6a&Host=slcsbpaymentsplatformserv3002.slc.paypal.com&pid=13409
< Content-Language: *
< Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 16:47:47 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 740
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"id":"PAY-3XB52861RA479681CKTPCVMY","
create_time":"2015-02-13T16:47:47Z",
"update_time":"2015-02-13T16:47:47Z",
"state":"created",
"intent":"sale",
"payer":{"payment_method":"paypal",
"payer_info":{"shipping_address":{}}},
"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"7.47","currency":"USD","details":   {"subtotal":"7.47"}},"related_resources":[]}],"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3XB52861RA479681CKTPCVMY","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-39015200YL315920D","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3XB52861RA479681CKTPCVMY/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"payment_method":"paypal"`

This means the user (your customer) must (these are the missing steps in above):

- be redirected to Paypal from your application to the `approval_url` returned in the response (their response to your last curl call).
- the user will/must "approve" your request
- user will be sent back to your site/application to the url you set in `return_url`
- you'll need to `execute` the payment after that.

Reference: [Accept a PayPal payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)

This essentially maps to "Express Checkout" in the Classic API.

Hth..

Comment: Thank you, EdSF.  I thought I was doing the Accept a Credit Card request, and that it should be done in one step.  You got me on track!